# Clamping values below threshold in Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.1.2

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a binary (black and white) texture that I used to set the z-value for geometry in a given example. I would like to set values to zero if they are below a certain threshold (black or almost black). How can I achieve this in geometry nodes? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Map Range* node to determine the lower and upper limits of your input value:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This node was exactly what I was looking for. :)